# How to define global variables in xcos/scicos block diagram simulation?

Tags: scilab, xcos

I want to define global variables in an xcos/scicos signal flow diagram. I tried the block `Simulation>set context`:

> [image]
>   [image]

But then it does not accept it as a known variable anywhere:

[image]

**P.S.** I tried the block diagram on a different computer and it now works with semicolons. Apparently this was a glitch or a bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is a bit strange but for some reason that semicolon at the end was the issue! So if you just omit the `;` and put variables line by line it all works out:

```
a = 2
b = 3
...
```

More elaborate tutorial on how/why using the `set context` [here](http://www.merrydowncontrolware.co.uk/mcl/Doing/Modelling/Scilab/setcontext.php).